# Android Java split on 4 integers

Tags: java, android, string, split

I receive an address in the form of "street number postcode city" (as a string).
What I want to do is split the street and number from the postcode and city. Normally you can split on whitespace. But some streetnames have also whitespace in them, example: "Emile Van Ermengemlaan". So split on whitespace is no option.

The postcode is always 4 single numbers for example "1234","8560", ... And I think this is the option. Split on the postcode. But I don't know how to do this. Any help?

EDIT:
Examples:

1. Example 1

   "Graaf Karel De Goedelaan 1 8500 Kortrijk" => "Graaf Karel de Goedelaan 1" next line "8500 Kortrijk"
2. Example 2

   "Reigerstraat 24 8930 Lauwe" => "Reigerstraat 24" next line "8930 Lauwe"

Comment: Can you give a couple of examples of what you are trying to match on?

Comment: Sorry, can you edit your question to show these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String input = "Graaf Karel De Goedelaan 1 8500 Kortrijk";
String[] results = input.split("([0-9]{4})");
String road = results[0].trim();
String city = results[1].trim();
String postcode = "";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{4})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while(m.find()) {
    postcode = m.group(1);
}
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println("Road: " + road);
System.out.println("Postcode: " + postcode);
System.out.println("City: " + city);
```

Gives: 
    Graaf Karel De Goedelaan 1 8500 Kortrijk
    Road: Graaf Karel De Goedelaan 1
    Postcode: 8500
    City: Kortrijk

And:
    Reigerstraat 24 8930 Lauwe
    Road: Reigerstraat 24
    Postcode: 8930
    City: Lauwe

Answer (score 1):

Thats something untested. I created it on the fly, there might be some mistakes but the general idea should fit.

```
String s = "Graaf Karel De Goedelaan 1 8500 Kortrijk";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("{4}[0-9]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find){
    String postcode = m.group(1);
}

// splits around postcode
String[] split = s.split({4}[0-9]);

p = Patter.compile("\D"); //non-digit
m = p.matcher(split[0]);
while(m.find){
    String street = m.group(1);
}


p = Patter.compile("\d"); //digit
m = p.matcher(split[0]);
while(m.find){
    String streetnumber = m.group(1);
}

String city = split[1].substring(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of code that works for me. It performs these operations:

1. It splits the string based on whitespace, and each element is stored on an array of strings;
2. It checks the size of each element of the array;
3. If the size is == 4 (the number of characters of the postal code), then it checks (with a pattern) if the current element is a number;
4. If the current element is a number, then this element and the next element (the city) is stored on an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

   ```
   import java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import java.util.regex.Pattern;
   import java.util.*; 
   public class split{

    private List<String> newline = new ArrayList<String>();

       public split(){
           String myString = "Graaf Karel De Goedelaan 1 8500 Kortrijk";
           String array[] = myString.split("\\s+");

           for(int z = 0;z<arr.length;z++){

               int sizestr = array[z].length();

               if(sizestr==4){/* if the generic string has 4 characters */
                   String expression = "[0-9]*";
                   CharSequence inputStr = array[z];  
                       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);  
                       Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);  
                       if(matcher.matches()){/* then if the string has 4 numbers, we have the postal code" */  
                               newline.add(array[z]); /* now we add the postal code and the next element to an array list" */
                               newline.add(array[z+1]);
                   }
               }

           }

           Iterator<String> itr = newline.iterator();
               while (itr.hasNext()) {
                   String element = itr.next();
                   System.out.println(element);
                   /* prints "8500" and "Kortrijk" */
               }
       }

       public static void main(String args[]){
           split s = new split();
       }
   }
   ```

For further info about the check of the string, take a look to this [page](http://www.zparacha.com/best-way-to-check-if-a-java-string-is-a-number/#.T1TX_ZeA8vs), and, for the ArrayList Iterator, see [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util/ArrayListiterator.htm).

I hope this can help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JGeocoder's [address parser](http://jgeocoder.sourceforge.net/parser.html).

Answer (score 0):

try the split command parsing the pattern ",", then you have only to parseInt

Comment: As you can see in the examples ther are no "," in the string